# The try catch catches the exception but the code after runs anyway cakephp

Tags: php, exception, cakephp, try-catch, cakephp-4.x

I'm doing policy authorization in CakePHP. For all CRUD methods, I have to test if the user has the right to execute them. So I create that method to use in all the methods:

Code in SchoolsController

```
private function authorize(School $s){
    try{
        $this->Authorization->authorize($s);
    } catch(ForbiddenException $e){
        $this->Flash->error("You don't have permission.");
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Schools', 'action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

I'm testing the code for a user who wouldn't have permission. This should work but the code after calling this method is still called.

```
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $school = $this->Schools->get($id);
        $this->authorize($school);

        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        if ($this->Schools->delete($school)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__("School has been successfully removed."));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__("The school could not be deleted. Please try again."));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

I'm redirected and I get the two messages:
"You don't have permission."
"School has been successfully removed."

Here my SchoolPolicy

```
    public function canDelete(IdentityInterface $user, School $school)
    {
        return $this->isAuthor($user,$school);
    }
    protected function isAuthor(IdentityInterface $user, School $school)
    {
        return $school->userId === $user->id;
    }
```

Comment: Either don't catch the exception in `authorize`, so it bubbles upwards in the hierachy, or exit (not return) after redirect. If you catch the exception, you handled it... therefore, normal execution will continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch an exception, then it will of course not halt execution, that's the whole point of catching it. And if you then return a value from your method (`Controller::redirect()` will return the response object with the `Location` header configured accordingly), you'll need to do something with that value, otherwise it will just vanish into the void, so for example:

```php
$response = $this->authorize($school);
if ($response) {
    return $response;
}
```

It's a bit hidden [**in the docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components.html#using-redirects-in-component-events), but the easier approach would be to throw a redirect exception from your `authorize()` method. Also, if you do not actually make any use of the forbidden exception and the information that it holds, then you could simply use the `can()` method, which returns a boolean, eg:

```
if (!$this->Authorization->can($s)) {
    $this->Flash->error("You don't have permission.");

    throw new \Cake\Http\Exception\RedirectException(
        \Cake\Routing\Router::url([
            'controller' => 'Schools',
            'action' => 'index',
        ])
    );
}
```

You may also want to consider using a [**custom unauthorized handler**](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/middleware.html#add-a-flash-message-after-being-redirected-by-an-unauthorized-request) instead.